# Simple imperative thing becomes complicated when trying to implement functional way without using variables

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have tree like structure

```
class T {
  properties:P
  children:Seq[T]
}
```

and I want to transform it to another tree like structure with some transformation applied to properties and with field for parent node:

```
class TT {
  properties:PP
  parent:TT
  children:Seq[TT]
}
```

Can't find a way to do this in functional style. Can you help?

**Especially for @om-nom-nom hard to imagine java code which should do the job:**

```
public class Omnomnom {
    static class P {
        String value;
    }

    static class PP {
        String value;
    }

    static class T {
        P properties;
        List<T> children;
    }

    static class TT {
        PP properties;
        TT parent;
        List<TT> children;
    }

    static PP transform_P_into_PP(P properties) {
        PP result = new PP();
        result.value = properties.value + "pff";
        return result;
    }

    public static TT transform_T_into_TT(T node, TT parent){
        TT current = new TT();
        current.parent = parent;
        current.properties = transform_P_into_PP(node.properties);

        List<TT> children = new LinkedList<>();
        current.children = children;

        for(T child : node.children) {
            children.add(transform_T_into_TT(child,current));
        }
        return current;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        T rootT = new T(); 
        TT rootTT = transform_T_into_TT(rootT,null);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you transform it in imperative way? Any sample code?

Comment: @om-nom-nom No, there will be no sample imperative way code :) I think this is irrelevant. Transformation of properties is just function call with P as parameter which returns PP.

Comment: then it's very bold statement about *simple imperative thing*. I mean, for me its not quite straight forward how to accomplish it in say, java, and the task in general not well formulated

Comment: @om-nom-nom sample for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally find the functional solution hugely clearer in this case. First I'll fix your definitions, which don't compile:

```
// Dummy definitions for the sake of a complete working example.
type P = Int
type PP = String

trait T {
  def properties: P
  def children: Seq[T]
}

trait TT {
  def properties: PP
  def parent: Option[TT]
  def children: Seq[TT]
}
```

The one substantive change I made is to the type of `parent`. Root nodes don't have a parent, and we don't want to use `null` if we're aiming for a functional approach, so we make it optional. Now the transformation definition is super simple:

```
def transform(f: P => PP)(t: T): TT = {
  def transformWithParent(op: Option[TT])(t: T): TT = new TT {
    val properties = f(t.properties)
    val parent = op
    val children: Seq[TT] = t.children.map(transformWithParent(Some(this)))
  }

  transformWithParent(None)(t)
}
```

And let's test it:

```
val myTree = new T {
  val properties = 3

  val children = Seq(
    new T {
      val properties = 4
      val children = Seq.empty
    },
    new T {
      val properties = 5
      val children = Seq.empty
    }
  )
}

val newTree = transform(_.toString)(myTree)
```

And then for example we can look at the second child of the root, find its parent (the root, of course), and get the parent's value:

```
scala> newTree.children(1).parent.map(_.properties)
res0: Option[PP] = Some(3)
```

Exactly as expected.

Comment: Ha :) it seemed to me so hard because I've started with case classes which I wanted to create like this: CaseClass(p1,p2,p3 ...) and that  makes usage of "this", like in your Some(this), not applicable.